# NET8 Maui IFingerprint doesn't stop to ask for authentication

Tags: c#, maui, fingerprint

In my `NET8` `MAUI` application, I added `Plugin.Fingerprint`. When a user wants to login in the app, I redirect the user to a *LoginPage*.

```
private readonly IFingerprint fingerprint;
public LoginPage(IFingerprint fingerprint)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this. Fingerprint = fingerprint;
}

async Task<bool> IsBiometricAvailable()
{
    return await fingerprint.IsAvailableAsync(true);
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    vm.Clean();

    var isAvailable = await IsBiometricAvailable();
}

private async Task ValidateBiometrics() {
    var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration("Access", 
        "Use your biometric to access the app.");
    var result = await fingerprint.AuthenticateAsync(request);
    if (result.Authenticated)
        GotoMainPage();
}

private async void imageButtonFinger_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ValidateBiometrics();
}

private void GotoMainPage()
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

From this code, I expect that only when I click the `imageButtonFinger`, the app calls the `ValidateBiometrics` to start the process of the biometric authentication. The real behaviour is that after checking `IsBiometricAvailable`, the app starts to ask again and again for biometric authentication.

This behaviour continues also if I change page.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code and saw that the line/s which are responsible for authenticating are being called again and again?

Comment: Try to debug and see if the line `GotoMainPage();` is called. If so, maybe there is a recursion problem in that function (I believe that there can be a connection, maybe not direct, between `GotoMainPage` and the authentication process.

Comment: Yes, after the `IsBiometricAvailable` there is no other call to the code at all.

Comment: I call `GotoMainPage();` to replace the `MainPage` from the `LoginPage` to the `new AppShell()` after the authentication.

Comment: What do you mean by `"to replace"`? don't you want to navigate to the main page after authentication? please tell me further how it works

Comment: I have just updated the code and you can see the method.

Comment: Try https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric instead :)